# How do I insert a JFreeChart chart into a panel which is on a separate GUI?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jfreechart

I need to put a chart into a new panel in a GUI class file using JFreeChart. I have 3 Java files: one with a button which calls the pie chart generator, one which creates the pie chart, and the other where the pie chart needs to be displayed. I have a button which creates the graph:

```
PieChartGenerator tweetSource = new PieChartGenerator(
    "Comparison", "What device are people using to Tweet?");
tweetSource.pack();
tweetSource.setVisible(true);
```

The specific GUI class file is called "Graphs", and the Panel is called "sourcePieChartPanel". The code which creates the chart is as follows:

```
public class PieChartGenerator extends JFrame {

public PieChartGenerator(String applicationTitle, String chartTitle) throws IOException {
    super(applicationTitle);

    PieDataset dataset = createDataset();
    JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset, chartTitle);

    ChartPanel pieChartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
    pieChartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(500, 270));
    setContentPane(pieChartPanel);
}

/**
 * Creates a sample dataset
 */
private PieDataset createDataset() throws IOException {
    DefaultPieDataset result = new DefaultPieDataset();
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\markc\\OneDrive\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\TwitterProject\\src\\text\\pieChartSource.txt");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(file);
    int twitterWebClient = 0;
    int tweetDeck = 0;
    int android = 0;
    int iphone = 0;
    int hootsuite = 0;
    int other = 0;

    while (s.hasNext()) {
        String Scan = s.nextLine();
        if (Scan.contains("Twitter Web Client")) {
            twitterWebClient++;
        } else if (Scan.contains("TweetDeck")) {
            tweetDeck++;
        } else if (Scan.contains("Twitter for Android")) {
            android++;
        } else if (Scan.contains("Twitter for iPhone")) {
            iphone++;
        } else if (Scan.contains("Hootsuite")) {
            iphone++;
        } else {
            other++;
        }
    }
    s.close();

    result.setValue("Twitter Web Client " + twitterWebClient, twitterWebClient);
    result.setValue("TweetDeck " + tweetDeck, tweetDeck);
    result.setValue("Android " + android, android);
    result.setValue("IPhone " + iphone, iphone);
    result.setValue("Hootsuite " + hootsuite, hootsuite);
    result.setValue("Other " + other, other);
    return result;

}

/**
 * Creates a chart
 */
private JFreeChart createChart(PieDataset dataset, String title) {

    JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createPieChart3D(title, dataset, true, true, false);

    PiePlot3D plot = (PiePlot3D) chart.getPlot();
    plot.setStartAngle(290);
    plot.setDirection(Rotation.CLOCKWISE);
    plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.5f);
    return chart;

}
```

This creates the pie chart and puts it into a new content panel called `pieChartPanel`. How could I implement this so that the new chart is displayed in a panel in the class file named `Graphs`?

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits the problem you describe; make `createDataset()` self-contained using _ad hoc_ data.

Comment: Are able to add a `getChart()` method to `PieChartGenerator`?